# Next gen data indexers

Tags: lucene, sphinx, new-operator, indexer

Are there any new technologies for indexing and fulltext + attributes data search? Better then sphinx, lucene etc?
Maybe some new products in early betas?

Better - I mean faster with HUGE amount of data 100M+ records - less memory usage, faster search etc, maybe with some build-it scalability features...

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details what you disappoint you with Sphinx?

Actually Sphinx could handle with easy even 1B+ collection and has build-in scalability features.

Comment: Several issues:

1) on 100M index searchd process uses A LOT of memory - 1GB+.
When there are several concurrent connection it becomes a problem.

2) Attributes search is slow too - requires fullscan.

So it would nice to hear about any new technologies to deal with these issues.

Comment: You could significantly lower the memory consumption by set higher values for these options prefix\infix_len, min_word_len, adding stopwords, lower the max_matches option, using workers=fork, using option ondisk_dict_default=1.

Comment: Attribute search is not raw fullscan - but could skip whole blocks of attributes considering min\max values into these blocks. That is why it should be no stall with attribute searching. Anyway you could split your index by parts and search for document that fit attribute condition via distributed index + dist_threads option